# Tensorflow Mean Absolute Error (MAE) for evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Looking at tensorflow docs for MAE, I saw that [tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_absolute_error) will return:

- `mean_absolute_error`: A Tensor representing the current mean, the value of total divided by count.
- `update_op`: An operation that increments the total and count variables appropriately and whose value matches mean_absolute_error.

How to implement this for evaluation purpose? As stated [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12252#issuecomment-322276355):

> mean_absolute_error is intended for evaluation and so it doesn't have a gradient. mean_absolute_error also returns an update op (which are you ignoring in the code above) that must be used to update the mean, so the concept of a gradient for this function doesn't really make sense. The update op for tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(pred, y) must be called before the mean can be obtained.

I don't know how to deal with returned value from `mean_absolute_error` function. Can someone write a simple example with this function? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are not sure what the returned tensors/operations mean and how to use them. Here is a nice article explaining the how as well as the why: http://ronny.rest/blog/post_2017_09_11_tf_metrics/

For a simple self-contained example usage you can see the tests. For example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cda36b817e9998906da37ec87c525f1b278c71a7/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/metrics_test.py#L2816

Comment: The article is useful enough for me. Detailed explained why and how we could use tf.metrics. Although it talk about accuracy but the same logic for mean absolute error.

Comment: Would you mind recap about the above articles, incase the article goes 404. @iga

Comment: article no longer available. @truongnm by any chance do you have any leads?

Comment: Sorry for slow response! You can use google webcache incase the link die. Google save the snapshot of every website.
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://ronny.rest/blog/post_2017_09_11_tf_metrics/

Anyway, I found the same article in steemit, the author post there too. 
https://steemit.com/machine-learning/@ronny.rest/avoiding-headaches-with-tf-metrics
@momo